# Продолжение выполнение цикла python

Tags: циклы, python-3.7

Есть такой цикл:

```
while True:
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            try:
                if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                    if event.from_user:
                        msg_1()
                        continue
                    if event.from_chat:
                        msg_2()
                        continue
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                os._exit(1)
    except:
        continue
```

Его суть заключается в том, чтобы получить сообщения от пользователя ВК, затем вызвать функцию `msg_1()`, если сообщение из ЛС, или `msg_2()`, если сообщение из беседы. Сами функции всего-то отправляют сообщения с результатами команд пользоватeлю и цикл продолжается.

Но есть проблема. Цикл **стоит** до тех пор, пока не придет ответ от вызванной функции. И из-за этого нельзя использовать бота одновременно в нескольких беседах. Это неудобно, когда в одной беседе большой поток команд, а другие не могут боту даже написать из-за этого.

**Нужно:** сделать так, чтобы после получения сообщения и вызова функции, цикл **шел дальше** (т.е принимал новые сообщения, даже если от функции еще не пришел ответ), а не **стоял**. Возможно ли такое сделать? Если да, то как?

Comment: *"Flat is better than nested"* ‒ [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё зависит от Вашего железа.

Если Вы используете одноядерный процессор, то заметите улучшения производительности только в некоторых ситуациях. К примеру, в случае ожидания чего-либо (будь то `time.sleep` или ответ от стороннего сервера)

Увы, но в большинстве случаев, производительность упадёт примерно в 2 раза. Это происходит от того, что Python использует **GIL** (*Global Interpreter Lock*) и очень хорошо оптимизирован под работу лишь в одном потоке.

---

Выбирать приходится из многопоточности ([`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)) и мультипроцессинга ([`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)).
Если у Вас несколько ядер, то рекомендуется `multiprocessing`, в ином случае `threading`.

Вот пример на `threading`:

```py
from threading import Thread


def msg_1():
    ...


def msg_2():
    ...

...
if event.from_user:
    t = Thread(target=msg_1)
    t.start()
    continue
if event.from_chat:
    t = Thread(target=msg_2)
    t.start()
    continue
...
```

Для того, чтобы переделать пример под `multiprocessing`, нужно обернуть основную часть программы в `if __name__ == '__main__':`. Подробнее читайте в документации.

---

**P. S.:**
Советую использовать для отправки сообщения одну и ту же функцию и запрос. У API ВК есть замечательный универсальный идентификатор (`peer_id`), в зависимости от которого сообщение отправится или в ЛС, или в беседу.

Comment: А вот тут теперь возникла проблема. Все сработало, да, но, вот пользователи пишут две разных команды (даже с разных бесед) в одно время (ну, совпало), бот почему-то путает беседы и отправляет ответы в противоположные беседы, но с правильными данными. Т.е допустим - один пишет "Бах", а другой пишет "Помощь", только первому почему-то отправляется список команд, а второму ответ на команду "Бах", хотя должно быть наоборот. Это можно как-то исправить? Ибо без мульти-потока такого не было.

Comment: @MrCreating Не думаю, что это из-за потоков. Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильность указания идентификаторов. Если ничего не найдёте, то прикрепите, пожалуйста, часть кода, которая работает не так, как Вы предполагаете. Постараюсь помочь.

Comment: Сделав `print()` событий с сервера - все идентификаторы, тексты правильны. Я предполагаю, что дело в функциях, ибо они вызывают класс из другого файла (с командами). Но бот все равно путает команды, хотя возвращает никнеймы игроков правильно, но не ответ. И происходит такой баг, только если написать команды разными людьми **одновременно**, иначе выполнится по очереди и правильно. Вот сами функции: (отправлю следующим комментарием)

Comment: `def msg_1():
    try:
        user_id = event.object.from_id
        bot = Bot(user_id)
        message = bot.new_message(event.object.text, event, user_id)
        if message == None or message == '':
            return 'empty'
        else:
            vk.messages.send(
                random_id=random.randrange(0, 9999999999999),
                peer_id=event.object.peer_id,
                message=message)
            return 'success'
    except:
        return 'error'`, где `vk` - вызов методов API напрямую, с помощью `vk_api,get_api()` (а вот форматирование пропадает..'